# How to display certain names in google maps infowindow marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm kind of stuck and was wondering if someone could help, here is a snippet of my code:

```
function test(person,address)
{
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.761539, -79.411079),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
    var marker, i;
    var clatlng, clat, clng;
    for (i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {  
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address[i]}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                clat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                clng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                clatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(clat, clng);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker) {
                    //cant add information here dont know why...
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(person[0].cName + "<br>" + results[0].formatted_address);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker));
            }
        });
    }//for
}//function
```

I'm passing an array of addresses and names. I've been trying to get each marker to display the person's name and address upon clicking on the infowindow of the marker on the map. This is where I'm having issues, I solved the address issue by just using the results[0].formatted_address but am unsure on how to display the specific user to that marker. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need function closure on the name as well as the marker in the click listener for the marker. As the name of the person needs to be available in the callback for the geocoder as well, you need function closure on the geocoder callback function as well.

**Related questions**

- [Google Maps V3 - I cannot reconcile closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271237/google-maps-v3-i-cannot-reconcile-closure)
- [JS Geocoder cannot assign Global Variable for Google Maps Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33770614/js-geocoder-cannot-assign-global-variable-for-google-maps-variable)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7he96ru/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function test(person, address) {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 5,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.761539, -79.411079),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
    var marker, i;
    var clatlng, clat, clng;
    for (i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address[i]
      }, (function(name) {
        return function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            clat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            clng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            clatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(clat, clng);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, name) {
              //cant add information here dont know why...
              return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(name + "<br>" + results[0].formatted_address);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
              }
            })(marker, name));
          }
        }
      })(person[i]));
    } //for
  } //function

function initialize() {
  test(["fred", "george", "frank"], ["New York, NY", "Newark, NJ", "Toronto, CA"]);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```